# Protect XSS on HTML generated from Markdown

Tags: php, laravel, security, markdown, xss

**Background:** I'm making a website similar to blog, where I want to allow users to write articles in `markdown`. This will be available publically so anyone cna write articles. Technologies used are `PHP` with `Laravel` framework.

**Solution used till now:** For preview, while writing article, I'm using [showdown](https://github.com/showdownjs/showdown). This works great to show preview and I'm not afraid about XSS during preview mode (author will hurt himself). However, when article is published, it must be XSS safe.

**Problem:** I'm saving markdown in database. Now while displaying article, I want markdown to be converted to HTML but at the same time, must be protected for XSS attacks. `Showdown` is not XSS safe. I also tried parsing Markdown through [Parsedown](https://github.com/erusev/parsedown) at server side, but it is also not XSS secured.

**Limitation:** I'm not security expert but I tested (for simple XSS attacks) that Github and stackoverflow markdown are secured against XSS attacks, so this must be possible. `I do not want to make custom XSS filter myself as I'm not subject matter expert and can't guaranty I covered all possible cases.`

Considering all this, could someone please suggest any library, preferably in `php` (AWS Lambda languages like Python, Go, JS also fine but not preferred), which may convert `markdown` to `html` and while protecting `XSS` and which libraries are used by github and stackoverflow to show HTML from markdown without XSS vulnerability.

> I can post code I developed till now (It is open source but do not want to commit without XSS filter) but it is not relevant for the question. Will share github link/commit later, after fixing XSS issue for future users.

Comment: it's a combination of things you'll have to do, of course, but I would recommend [thoroughly reading this very, very in depth article on XSS and Markdown](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/06/preventing-xss-vulnerabilities-in-php-everything-you-need-know)

Comment: Hi Ohgodwhy 

Thanks for the link. I'm going through it and already went through few others on XSS. However, this will be a custom solution and after following all things given in the article, can I be 100% sure about XSS attacks? Also, if some vulnerability found in future, how will I know about it and fix my custom solution.

Although I feel there must be solutions (open source libraries), I will make my own open source solution if I do not find existing one. Just I want to save my free time/energy for open source product I'm making right now.

Comment: I can assure you of 1 thing: in the development world, no solution to anything is ever 100%. That article recommends 2 libraries that handle the bulk of the work, and you just lay another helper function on top. You can always hire a certified freelance OWASP company to pen-test after you've implemented to be certain.

Comment: I suggest reading [Markdown and XSS](https://michelf.ca/blog/2010/markdown-and-xss/) by Michel Fortin, the developer of PHP Markdown. It covers all of the potential dangers well and the proper way to protect against them.

Comment: Thanks Waylan and Ohgodwhy for helpful articles. I found working solution but still going though articles you shared and other to confirm my site is XSS secured. Will share code once finished, probably by weekend.